# How can I replace all vh units to fixed pixel values for mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-safari, android-softkeyboard, viewport-units

My website uses `vh` units for practically everything: font-sizes, positions, heights, and widths. Due to the nature of my website, this is how I chose to make it responsive across different aspect ratios.

The problems are on mobile:

1. **Android's soft keyboard** shrinks the viewport, and in turn, my content, to the point where it's unreadable:

   [image: Take a look]
2. **Mobile Safari's address bar** jarringly shrinks and expands the viewport and my content when it appears and disappears as you change scroll direction.

I saw some potential solutions on Stack Overflow, but none of the quick, per-element, manual fixes worked for my case in which almost every element uses `vh`.

I was hoping to use jQuery to detect mobile, and if true, somehow replace all `vh` units across my CSS with fixed pixel values, and maybe refresh this function on an orientation change (if the user switches from portrait to landscape or vice versa).

How would I write this code?

Comment: Have you tried `vmax` instead of `vh`?

Comment: Use a media query in which you set sizes to px for small screens. Or use things like min-width and min-height to restrict the sizes. Oh, and you don't have to use `vh` for everything. If you know the font size for any element, you can set its dimensions in `em` instead. That way you will have to change only one unit when redesigning.